# How to make sure the complete string between a delimiter fits a regex pattern?

Tags: regex

I want to create a regex pattern, that will validate numbering of between a delimiter `;`. This means the following examples are allowed:

```
1; 2;3;4; 5; 
1-10; 11 - 20; 21- 30;31-40;41-50; 51-60;
a; b;c;d; e; f;
a - c; d-g;h-m;n-s; t - z;
```

Not allowed would be the following:

```
asdf; 
1-c;
a - 10;
@ - *; 
+; 
1 - 10+;
\\ and so on
```

So far I have come up with the following regex pattern:

```
\s*((\b\w\b)|(\b\w\b)\s*\-\s*(\b\w\b)|(\d+)|(\d+)\s*\-\s*(\d+));\s*
```

However, if I test for example `a - 10;` it will mark  `10;` as valid result. The question therefore is, how can I enforce, that the complete string within the delimiters must comply to the given pattern, not just parts of it?

**Additional question:** Would it be possible in range cases (patterns containing `-`) to check if the second number is higher than the first one / the second character comes later in the alphabet than the first one? So far I could only find checks for static numbers.

Comment: What about "1-10;a-b;" for example?

Comment: @JvdV `1-10;a-b;` should be valid.

Comment: I had an answer down, but you now have sample data including a comma. Is that on purpose or a typo?

Comment: OH sh.., yes sorry, is a type, will edit immediately!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can use:

```
^(?: ?(?:\d+(?: ?- ?\d+)?|[a-z](?: ?- ?[a-z])?);)+$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/k4OAg8/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?:` - Open 1st non capture group:

  - `?` - An optional space.
  - `(?:` - Open 2nd non capture group:

    - `\d+` - 1+ digits
    - `(?:` - Open 3rd non-capture group:

      - `?- ?\d+` - An optional space, a dash and another optional space followed by 1+ digits.
      - `)?` - Close 3rd non-capture group and make it optional.
    - `|` - Or:
    - `[a-z]` - A character ranging from a-z.
    - `(?:` - Open 4th non-capture group:

      - `?- ?\d+` - An optional space, a dash and another optional space followed by a character ranging from a-z.
      - `)?` - Close 4th non-capture group and make it optional.
    - `);` - Close 2nd non-capture group and match a semi-colon.
  - `)+` - Close 1st non-capture group and make it match 1+ times.
- `$` - End string anchor.

I don't know if you'd want to check for higher/lower inside the regex or if it's even possible (which I doubt).

Comment: I think this is pretty much it, however for some reason it doesn't detect matches on `1; 2;3;4; 5; ` or `1; 2-10; a; x; x;b - c;` But to be honest, I'll have just pasted those in, I'll have to go through your explanation a bit to see what is happening.

Comment: @RolandDeschain, that is because of the trailing spaces when you pasted those values. If you want to allow for a trailing space you can add an optional space right before the end string anchor.